# How to manage credentials for different environments in Rails 5.2?

Tags: amazon-s3, environment-variables, credentials, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm (still/always) new to Rails. While I was building my project Rails upgraded to v5.2 with [encrypted credentials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials). Now I'm about to deploy to production and found that I do not understand how to separate production credentials from development. And I'm not sure that I know how I would do it in v5.1. So how to make it in Rails 5.2?

Answer (score 6):

I solved my issue using this code

*If in your credentials file like this*

```
development: 
    stripe_secret_key: 123
production:
    stripe_secret_key: 345
test:
    stripe_secret_key: 678
```

**1'st solution:**

`Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe_secret_key]`

**2'nd solution:**

*open `application.rb` file and define `self.credentials` method*

```
module ModuleName
    class Application < Rails::Application
        def self.credentials
            @credentials ||= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym]
        end
    end 
end
```

*And use*

`ModuleName.credentials[:stripe_secret_key]`

More info please refer [link](https://dev.to/svyatov/easier-usage-of-rails-52-credentials-and-app-specific-configuration-461g)

Answer (score 2):

I've found the [`rails-env-credentials`](https://github.com/sinsoku/rails-env-credentials) gem useful for this. Not sure how compatible it will be with the upcoming Rails 6 support but its been working great for my app.

Comment: oh yes that's precisely what I want. Funny, I had specified these precise requirements for myself when looking over solutions. This looks exactly right to me. Thanks Eric !

Comment: this way you can further segregate by developer or developer-level and, for example, have a setup where you not give out your master key to contractors

Answer (score 1):

I believe the idea is not to have multiple environments in your credentials file, but to have multiple credentials files.

We solved it by having `credentials.dev.enc`, `credentials.production.enc`, etc.

Then we upload the specific file to the specific server as part of the deploy process.

This also allows your environments to have independent master keys and encryption keys, which reduces the security risks in your system.

Comment: Would be cool. Are there any docs (or at least plans) how to make it this way? Or it's already working and I just didn't find that in docs?

Comment: As part of the deployment we simply upload the file matching the environment and rename it. This way the production or staging env only sees a single credentials file.

Comment: I like this answer but I don't understand how to implement it. when I run `bin/rake rails credentials:edit` does the task automatically match the `.dev` to your environment named `dev` (not `development`?)? How can I take my existing credentials file, decrypt it, and save it back to `.dev.enc` or `.production.enc` ? And then how do I tell Rails to pick up (that is, read from) that file when booting and decrypting my ENV vars? thanks.

Comment: Hi @JasonFB. We used to have a home-brew for this (back when I wrote the answer). Now we use rails-env-credentials, which is also Eric's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

While @dhh and @morgoth [promise to add environment management to Rails 6](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33521), I solved my task this way, and all looks like working good:

```
# application.rb
class Application < Rails::Application
    if Rails.env.development?
        ENV["access_key_id"] = Rails.application.credentials.DEV_aws[:access_key_id]
        ENV["secret_access_key"] = Rails.application.credentials.DEV_aws[:secret_access_key]
        ENV["s3_bucket_name"] = Rails.application.credentials.DEV_aws[:s3_bucket_name]
    end
    if Rails.env.production?
        ENV["access_key_id"] = Rails.application.credentials.PROD_aws[:access_key_id]
        ***
    end
end
```

All is in on place and encrypted

Comment: this seems annoyingly not DRY, like it would get messy quickly if you had dev, staging, + prod and also many env variables.

Comment: I guess I tend to have many environments— production, staging, multiple QA envs, and possibly a setup with a QA -env specific to each contractor, so you don't have to give your contractors full access to the prod credentials. in this setup, the same master key still decrypts all 3 so then you still use the same master key in all environments, which actually then becomes an attack vector. (meaning, the more places your master key is out there the more opportunities for it to get stolen)

Answer (score 0):

Sampson Crowley on Rails-talk list:

for rails 5, just nest environment specific credentials under a key for said environment

then all you have to do when accessing said config is add the environment to the party that pulls in config, e.g.:

credentials.yml.enc:

main_key:
  development:
    sub_key:
      value_key: 'development'
  production:
    sub_key:
      value_key: 'production'
  test:
    sub_key:
      value_key: 'test'

code:

```
my_credential = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:main_key, Rails.env.to_sym, :sub_key, :value_key)
```

Comment: I think this solution seems the most Rails 5.2 friendly, but ideally isn't the perfect solution as ideally you could in fact (one day, in Rails 6, say), separate the 3 files themselves, so you could, say, give junior developers access to only development+staging credentials by giving the only the keys for the development + staging master keys (but continuing to check-in all 3 .yml.enc files into source-code. the 3 keys are of course, not checked-in)

But if you have a team where you don't care if all the devs have the same (full) credentials then I like this solution best.

-Jason